# Celery apply_async pass kwargs to all tasks in chain

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

A Celery task queue to calculate result of (2 + 2) - 3.

```
@app.task()
def add(**kwargs):
    time.sleep(5)
    x, y = kwargs['add'][0], kwargs['add'][1]
    return x + y

@app.task()
def sub(**kwargs):
    time.sleep(5)
    x = args[0]
    y = kwargs['sub'][0]
    return x - y
```

Sample task data = `kwargs = {'add' : (2, 2), 'sub' : (3)}`
Chaining the tasks: `result = (add.s() | sub.s()).apply_async(kwargs = kwargs)`

[As per design](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/f7f5bcfceca692d0e78c742a7c09c424f53d915b/celery/canvas.py#L718-L725), apply_async only applies the kwargs to the first task in the chain. What do I need to change to achieve the desired outcome?

Comment: The linked task will be applied with the result of its parent task as the first argument,
so you can modify the `return` to include `kwargs`

Comment: In reality, the tasks will perform very different things. For eg - task1 - Open browser to `url`. task2 - send `data` to specific `input` fields.  You can see that its not a good design to return stuff from the task1.

Comment: Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as of Celery v4.4.0rc4 there is no better way to do this other than passing kwargs to each task's signature. Although it does look like [Ask Solem (Celery dev) is open to a feature request.](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2695#issuecomment-137602741).

This is how the chain should look like:

```
result = (add.s(job_data = job_data)| sub.s(job_data = job_data)).apply_async()
```

However since our chains have 10+ tasks, I had to come up with an easier way to write this.

```
# Workflow generator
def workflow_generator(task_list, job_data):
    _tasks = tuple(getattr(task, 's')(job_data = job_data) for task in task_list)
    return chain(*_tasks).apply_async()

taskList = [add, sub]
job_data = {'add' : (2, 2), 'sub' : (3)}
result = workflow_generator(taskList, job_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just partially bind the tasks before chaining them?

```
result = (add.s(add=(2,2)) | sub.s(sub=(3,3))).apply_async()
```